# Is it possible to create another control inside custom View class?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to create another control inside a custom View class.

I want to add an image and a progress bar inside a custom class.

There is no addView method in View class.

Is ViewGroup is the only option?

Comment: You can also extends one of the commom Layout (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout) based on your used cased and inflate the xml layout from there. BTW can you show us what you did it would be helpfull to provide you a better answer

Comment: Basically you need to extend ViewGroup or something else that already does so and does most of the work for you like a layout

Comment: extending Layout works.
Thanks @Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CustomClass extends FrameLayout {
    Context c;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView imageView;
    public CustomClass(Context context) {
       super(context);
       loadControls(context);
    }
    public CustomClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        loadControls(context);
    }
    public CustomClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        loadControls(context);
    }
    public void loadControls(Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        progressBar = new ProgressBar(c, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleInverse);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);

        imageView = new ImageView(c);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        //imageView.setBackgroundColor(color.darker_gray);
       addView(imageView, params);
       params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    addView(progressBar, params);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a custom View class you can inflate a layout. In the custom View classes constructor just call `inflate(context, R.layout.custom_layout, this);` and in custom_layout put a ProgressBar and an ImageView. When doing this have the custom View extend the same View class that is the root of `custom_layout` Eg if the root of custom_layout is a LinearLayout, extend LinearLayout.